# How to install and configure Microsoft Monitoring Agent for use with OMS Gateway (Proxy) using PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-monitoring, azure-rm-template

How can you use Powershell to install and configure the Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA) for use with the OMS Gateway ? ***None of the automated examples tell you how to accomplish this for use with an OMS Gateway.***

I found this as a walk-through to do this **manually**:
http://azurepost.com/oms-gateway-ga-installation-configuration-walkthrough/

and this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/gateway

**Automating:**

this one is for ARM templates, ***but does not support OMS Gateway***:
[Enabling the Microsoft Monitoring Agent in Windows JSON Templates](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/manageabilityguys/2015/11/19/enabling-the-microsoft-monitoring-agent-in-windows-json-templates/)

this one for Powershell, *but does not support OMS Gateway* [oms-windows.md](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows.md)

**None of the automated examples tell you how to accomplish this for use with an OMS Gateway.**
In fact from the documentation at [Property values](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/extensions/oms-windows.md#property-values) it appears to not be possible. Only properties documented are workspaceId and  workspaceKey. No  other properties (ie proxy, userid, password) needed for OMS Gateway configuration are listed.

Comment: Could you tell me what is "from the documentation at Property values it appears to not be possible"? These properties are used for arm template?

Comment: Read table in link. No props documented that could support this.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: To deploy and configure the MMA for use with OMS Gateway via ARM or PS. *These properties work with ARM as well as PS. PS usually builds ARM template under the hood.*  The full set of properties are:

**Documented Extension Properties**

- workspaceId
- workspaceKey

**Undocumented Extension Properties**

Control Panel;Microsoft Monitoring Agent app to determine what most of these values mean.

- **enableAutomaticManagement**: equivalent to "Tab: 'Operations Manager', Automatic update management group assignments for AD DS"
- **proxyUri**: equivalent to "Tab: 'Proxy Settings', Proxy Server"
- **proxyUser**: equivalent to "Tab: 'Proxy Settings', Username"
- **proxyPassword**: #equivalent to "Tab: 'Proxy Settings', Password"
- **azureRegionId**: Not sure, but I think it may be related to Log Analytics being in a different region. Use Get-AzureRMLocation, Location to determine valid values
- **stopOnMultipleConnections** : ???
- **azureResourceId**: ???

**Deploy via Powershell:**

```
Import-Module Az.Compute
Connect-AzAccount 
Set-AzContext -Subscription  $subscriptionId

$settings = @{ `
    "workspaceId" = $workspaceId; `
    "proxyUri" = $proxyUri; `
    "azureRegionId" = $azureRegionId `
}
$protectedSettings = @{"workspaceKey" = $workspaceKey}

$extensions = Get-AzVMExtension `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -VMName $vmName 

#If extension was already installed and the ExtensionName is not 'MicrosoftMonitoringAgent',
#re-install will fail. Therefore, we need to remove extension before proceeding.
foreach($extension in $extensions)
{
    if ($extension.ExtensionType -eq "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent")
    {
        Remove-AzVMExtension `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
            -VMName $vmName `
            -Name $extension.Name `
            -Confirm:$false `
            -Force:$true
    }

}

#install MMA Extension
$guid = New-Guid 
Set-AzVMExtension `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -VMName $vmName `
    -ExtensionType "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
    -ExtensionName "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent" `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion 1.0 `
    -ForceRerun $guid `
    -Settings $settings `
    -ProtectedSettings $protectedSettings `
    -Location $azureRegionId
```

**Deploy via ARM Template**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "serverName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "workspaceId": {
      "type": "string",
      //from the blob's etag property; changes each time update occurs
      "defaultValue": "guid-guid-guid-guid",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "To be provided from keyvault; equivalent to Tab: 'Azure Log Analytics (OMS)', Add or Edit Popup"
      }
    },
    "proxyUri": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "101.102.103.104:8080",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "To be provided from keyvault; equivalent to Tab: 'Proxy Settings', Proxy Server"
      }
    },
    "workspaceKey": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "defaultValue": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "To be provided from keyvault; equivalent to Tab: 'Azure Log Analytics (OMS)', Add or Edit Popup"
      }
    },

    "forceUpdateTag": {
      "defaultValue": "[newGuid()]",
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Forces extension to deploy every time."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/MicrosoftMonitoringAgent')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring",
        "type": "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": "true",
        "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('forceUpdateTag')]",
        "settings": {
          "workspaceId": "[parameters('workspaceId')]",
          "proxyUri": "[parameters('proxyUri')]",
          "azureRegionId": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "workspaceKey": "[parameters('workspaceKey')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*(please somebody tell me I wasted my time and there is a "Interogate Extension" powershell command somewhere...)*
How did I figure this out ? I used the portal to deploy the MMA Extension. I went to the VM and found the installed extension at :
    **C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent**

I decompiled:
**Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent.ExtensionShared.dll** and looked for the exact strings: **workspaceId** and **workspaceKey**. I found the classes: MMAExtensionPublicSettings, MMAExtensionProtectedSettings. These classes contain the valid Extension properties.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent.Extension.MMADataModels
{
    public class MMAExtensionPublicSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "azureRegionId")]
        public string AzureRegionId{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "azureResourceId")]
        public string AzureResourceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enableAutomaticManagement")]
        public bool EnableAutomaticManagement { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "proxyUri")]
        public string ProxyUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "proxyUser")]
        public string ProxyUser { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stopOnMultipleConnections")]
        public bool StopOnMultipleConnections { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "workspaceId")]
        public string WorkspaceId { get; set; }
        public MMAExtensionPublicSettings()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

** - MMAExtensionProtectedSettings

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;    
namespace Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent.Extension.MMADataModels
{
    public class MMAExtensionProtectedSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="proxyPassword")]
        public string ProxyPassword
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="workspaceKey")]
        public string WorkspaceKey
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public MMAExtensionProtectedSettings()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It irritates me that you only had 0 upvotes.  Thanks for taking the time.  You deserve 20.  Cheers.